# How can I connect to an IPv6 address on Android?

Tags: android, ipv6, google-tv

On Android, I'm using [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) to connect to a web address like so:

```
String url = "http://[fe80::1cef:49e7:2661:ffda]:7001/a.MOV";
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
```

The code works fine when inputting a standard URL, or one with a v4 IP address. However, when I use a v6 address, the last line of the above code will fail with a `java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument` being thrown.

To illustrate, while this address:

```
http://192.168.1.2:7001/a.MOV
```

will work without a problem, this one:

```
http://[fe80::1cef:49e7:2661:ffda]:7001/a.MOV
```

won't work at all.

To be sure, I also tried using the newer [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to make the connection, and it still results in the same exception being thrown.

I'm currently performing my testing on a Google TV device running Android version 3.2.

So is there something I'm doing wrong? And if not, is there any way to work around this apparent limitation of Android?

Comment: When using link-local addresses (starting with `fe..:`) then you have to specify the link you want to use. So it might be something like `http://[fe80::1cef:49e7:2661:ffda%eth0]:7001/a.MOV`. Better to use global addresses or ULA addresses if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `Android 3.2` It will not support `ipv6`

Check here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3718/does-android-have-support-for-ipv6

Comment: Looks like that's the case as I continue to try more and more things. Is there any way to work around this sort of thing? Or am I really stuck?

Comment: I think you are stuck, theres no workaround since your android version is old, may be you can upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `HttpGet(URI uri)` constructor.
Define the address in an `URI` object. Look at the examples here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html

You can also provide an IPV6 hostname.

Answer (score 0):

If you instead construct [a new URL from parts][1], you should be able to provide it into your HttpGet without any problems.

The constructor you're looking for is:

```
new URL(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String)
```

(Pardon the formatting, I'm on a phone.)

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String)

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I even tried just creating a socket with the InetAddress and even that won't work (same error).

Comment: If you're still getting an invalid argument as the SocketException, it seems to suggest that the device may not support IPv6. If it's instead a connectivity problem, perhaps your network infrastructure doesn't support IPv6?